# Android Keystore?.getKey returns null on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-security, android-fingerprint-api

I'm implementing fingerprint authentication in my application. I faced the problem that in doesn't work properly on some devices and my application crashes. Nevertheless, it works on some devices too. The issue is in this line

```
val key = keyStore?.getKey(Constants.FINGERPRINT_KEY_NAME, null) as SecretKey
```

The LogCat says:

```
 11-02 14:27:42.825 E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: kyivenergo.ua.kyivenegro, PID: 2298
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kyivenergo.ua.kyivenegro/ua.dtec.appOk.ui.screens.splash.SplashScreenActivity}: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type javax.crypto.SecretKey
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                   Caused by: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type javax.crypto.SecretKey
                      at ua.dtec.appOk.ui.dialog.FingerprintDialog.initCipher(FingerprintDialog.kt:222)
                      at ua.dtec.appOk.ui.dialog.FingerprintDialog.doCheck(FingerprintDialog.kt:147)
                      at ua.dtec.appOk.ui.dialog.FingerprintDialog.show(FingerprintDialog.kt:65)
                      at ua.dtec.appOk.ui.screens.splash.SplashScreenActivity.showFingerprintDialog(SplashScreenActivity.kt:55)
                      at ua.dtec.appOk.ui.screens.splash.SplashScreenActivity.onStart(SplashScreenActivity.kt:33)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
                      at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Here's my full code:

```
private fun doCheck() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        keyguardManager =
                c.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
        fingerprintManager =
                c.getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE) as FingerprintManager

        if (!fingerprintManager!!.isHardwareDetected()) {

            Toast.makeText(c, R.string.dialog_fingerprint_no_hardware_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(c, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Toast.makeText(c, R.string.dialog_fingerprint_enable_fingerprint_permission, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        if (!fingerprintManager!!.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

            Toast.makeText(c, R.string.dialog_fingerprint_no_fingerprints, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        if (!keyguardManager?.isKeyguardSecure()!!) {
            Toast.makeText(c, R.string.dialog_fingerprint_no_lock_screen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {

            generateKey()

        }

        if (initCipher()) {
            cryptoObject = FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher)

            helper = FingerPrintHelper(dialog!!)
            helper?.FingerprintHandler(c)
            helper?.startAuth(fingerprintManager!!, cryptoObject!!)
        }

    }
}

private fun generateKey() {

    try {

        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore")
            keyStore?.load(null)
            keyGenerator!!.init(

                    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(Constants.FINGERPRINT_KEY_NAME,
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                            .setEncryptionPaddings(
                                    KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                            .build())
        }

        keyGenerator?.generateKey()

    } catch (exc: KeyStoreException) {
        exc.printStackTrace()
        throw FingerprintException(exc)
    } catch (exc: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        exc.printStackTrace()
        throw FingerprintException(exc)
    } catch (exc: NoSuchProviderException) {
        exc.printStackTrace()
        throw FingerprintException(exc)
    } catch (exc: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException) {
        exc.printStackTrace()
        throw FingerprintException(exc)
    } catch (exc: CertificateException) {
        exc.printStackTrace()
        throw FingerprintException(exc)
    } catch (exc: IOException) {
        exc.printStackTrace()
        throw FingerprintException(exc)
    }

}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
fun initCipher(): Boolean {
    try {

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                        + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e)
    } catch (e: NoSuchPaddingException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e)
    }

    try {
        keyStore?.load(
                null)
        val key = keyStore?.getKey(Constants.FINGERPRINT_KEY_NAME, null) as SecretKey

        cipher?.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
        return true
    } catch (e: KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException) {

        return false
    } catch (e: KeyStoreException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
    } catch (e: CertificateException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
    } catch (e: UnrecoverableKeyException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
    } catch (e: InvalidKeyException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e)
    }

}
```

Comment: The stacktrace itself is more important than the error message. Especially since this error is cause by another one. Therefore could you add it please?

Comment: @tynn I edited my question

Comment: Are you sure `generateKey()` get called without any error?

Comment: So many `!!` in the code above :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're casting null to `SecretKey` which is non-nullable

```
val key = keyStore?.getKey(Constants.FINGERPRINT_KEY_NAME, null) as SecretKey
```

Here you could get null when `keyStore` is null or if `getKey()` returns null (if the given alias does not exist or does not identify a key-related entry).

So it's perfectly fine to get null there. Since you're upcasting, you might even run into a `ClassCastException`. To prevent this just use the type-safe cast operator `as?` instead.

```
val key: SecretKey? = keyStore?.getKey(Constants.FINGERPRINT_KEY_NAME, null) as? SecretKey
```

Comment: I got null in many HAUWEI devices when run `getKey()`, but `as?` doesn't solve the problem, since there will be further crashes with calling `Cipher` methods with null-SecretKey

Comment: @alla if the key is null, you cannot use it and have to handle the case differently. This question and answer is about safe casting with the `as?` operator. I'd suggest to you to ask another question about your specific problem.

Comment: it actually not specific, it would be duplicated question, so the same as the current with the same description and the same exception, but I will try

Comment: @alla you'll have to use `as?` non the less. The _further crashes_ are a different issue  you'll have to solve differntly.

Answer (score 0):

Build version should be greater than or equal to marshmallow.
If you trying less than M then it can raised error ..

Comment: I know this and took it into account